# Radio Button on Adobe Flash Mobile

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, radio-button

I am trying to have radio button on adobe flash. I have the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="HomeView">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:RadioButton groupName="Language"
               id="java"
               label="java"
               width="100"
               />

    <s:RadioButton groupName="Language"
               id="C"
               label="C"
               width="150"
               height="150"/>

    <s:RadioButton groupName="Language"
               id="Cplus"
               label="C++"
               width="200"
               height="200"/>
</s:View>
```

this will enable only the last radio button, but not all. can anyone suggest about the solution?

Comment: You should not use so many points in your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "enable".  Based on the code all the radio buttons should be enabled.

Your code is missing a formal [RadioButtonGroup](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/RadioButtonGroup.html) instance.  Add one in your declaration:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:RadioButtonGroup id="Language" />
</fx:Declarations>
```

I wonder if that may be your issue?

Comment: enable here..i am getting 3 radio buttons....but i am not able to select(first two) C,Java radio buttons

Comment: I got the solution...: <s:Spacer height="100" /> should be used after each button.....thank you all ..for your valuable suggestions...

Comment: Adding a spacer would not change the enablement / disablement of a button.  Possibly you had a layout issue.  It is not obvious from the code you displayed.